# session wiped out between pages

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm making a login page and for some reason the session will not persist between where I set it and the page where I am forwarding to. I can comment out the header in the page where the session was initialized and see that the session has the data in it. However, when I do a print_r in the target page, the session is empty.

I have already made sure that session_start is called. There is only one domain for this site and my browser is set to accept cookies. I can forward to any other page and see the session data but just not this one.

Is there something that someone can offer to help in debugging this?

```
$_SESSION['auth'] = $auth;
header( "Location: /" ); // commenting this out shows the data is in fact there
```

I want to protect the index page so I test to see if session['auth'] is set. If not, I forward over to /user/login which allows the user to login. If successful then we forward back over to the index page where it **should** pass the isset session test. It fails though and there is no session data.

Comment: Yes, Dan, it is. I can do a print_r of the session_id too on both pages.

Comment: Well, do you have the same session id for both pages?

Comment: @jim: when you say you made sure session_start was called, do you mean on both pages or just the one you're setting the session variables?  You need to call session_start on all pages even if they are only retrieving session data.

Comment: @zerkms, I do in fact have the exact same id for both pages

Comment: @rla, I have verified that the session_id is the same for both pages so would indicate that I am good there.

Comment: @jim: If you have the same session id and don't clear your session manually - then it is not possible.

Comment: @zerkms. I'd agree with you and I'm no stranger to sessions but this is over the top. I can't figure it out. I've removed ALL code in the index page with the exception of the session_start and the print_r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['auth'] = true;

header('Location: /');
```

index.php:

```
session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Create these 2 files and request set.php. What do you see?

Comment: OK, I'll come back in a minute or two

Comment: @zerkms, I get: `array(0) { }`

Comment: I'd suggest trying a different browser, or checking your session cookie params.  Another thought is your tmp dir or where your sesson is being stored on disk its full?

Comment: @jim: it is not possible :-S remove redirect now and right after requesting set.php try to look at session directory (do you have default handler to store sessions?) and find out the file that belongs current session. Is it blank?

Comment: @superfro: i thought about insufficient space or rights to write too, but in that case php should throw warning/fatal. Or php shouldn't? Never even tried :-S

Comment: @Superfro, I've tried it with Opera, FF and Chrome. I get the same thing in all of them. BTW: I also agree with Zerkms

Comment: @jim: do you have display_errors = 1, and error_reporting = E_ALL?

Comment: @Zerkms, I'm using a database to store the session. I'm not getting any errors of any kind. Will try your suggestion on the redirect

Comment: Try restarting apache (You are using apache right ?), clear your cookies, turn off anti virus, make sure you have free disk space on your server, check the tmp dir and see if you see the session files...  There's really not too many other options left of why zerk's example wouldn't work.  Your session isn't going to disk and being restored on the next page... the reason you see it when you turn off the redirect is because its still in memory, it should be flushed to disk, then reloaded by the next page's session_start but you are getting blank...

Comment: @zerk: This right from my ini file: `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`

Comment: "I'm using a database to store the session. I'm not getting any errors of any kind. Will try your suggestion on the redirect" --- well, then your database session handler is broken.

Comment: @Zerkms, I've tried your redirect suggestion. I've commented out the header, replaced `true` with my data and then went to the index page. I'm forwarded over to /user/login where I login successfully and then shown all of my data. It's all there, man. This is making me nuts. What could be happening after the redirect????

Comment: I'm telling you... Man, this has been making me into loon. I can't remember when the last time I;ve had to deal with a bug that was so darn bad. I'm not a noob to PHP but I'm truly humbled. I don't know what to do.

Comment: @jim: what value has your `session.save_handler`?

Comment: @jim how about your database schema for the session data ?  Whats the value of $auth ?

Comment: @Zerk, This is what I have: `session.save_handler = files`

Comment: @Superfro, The database has an empty string there. All of the other data is there though such as the session_id, just no session data

Comment: @jim: well, you keep your session data in files. How is that related to database?

Comment: @Superfro, I've wiped out the session table, cleared my browser of any cache then gone to the index page again. I **did not** log in but immediately went to the db table and can see that a new session was inserted. Again, no session data

Comment: @Zerk, I wrote a session script that uses a database to store this data. Now, before you get any ideas about this, let me say that I have been using this script for the past 2 years without a hitch of any kind. It's not the database script. Trust me on that. :)

Comment: @jim: I don't trust you, I trust the results. I've asked you to try my 2 simple scripts. Did you try **THEM**? Without any modifications?

Comment: Yes, I did try it exactly as you said. Lets look at this logically... If I can clear out my browser cache, clear the session table then surf to the index page and see a brand new entry in the database minus the session data, wouldn't that indicate to you that session_start is being called? I've also disabled the db script and went with just your suggestion and get exactly the same results.

Comment: Let me do one even better.. Let me take your suggestion outside of this project totally. I'll be right back with the results.

Comment: @jim well the problem is, all tests lead to a bug in your save_handler, since your session.save_handler is set to files, I presume you have some session_set_save_handler() calls, which if you try turning off your script so it will write to disk, and it begins to work, then you have a problem with your database script =(

Comment: "Let me do one even better.. Let me take your suggestion outside of this project totally." --- that is what i asked. To run **only** my 2 scripts, to get that sessions works fine, but your code - doesn't.

Comment: @Zerk, the result I get with I copy and paste your suggestion into 2 brand new files is `NULL`

Comment: @Zerk, a correction in the result... I forgot to add session_start to the target page. Here is the result: `array(1) { ["auth"]=> bool(true) }`

Comment: Yes, native session works. And your handler not. Do you need any other proofs?

Comment: I don't need to prove anything. I just need to find out what is wiping out the session. I've never had any issues using this db script and I highly doubt that is the cause. Now, something else may be stopping the session data from going in but my money is on the fact that it isn't the script. If you're so certain that it may be the script, please tell me how it is that all other data in every other area of the site are saved without any issues? There are also redirects in those areas as well. Sorry Zerk, it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @jim: I cannot say why your script fails (since i don't see it), but I definitely can say it fails, because **it doesn't work**. Despite the fact it works in other places - it doesn't here. So take debugger/var_dump() and debug your script. Nothing magic is here - you just made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @Zerk, thanks. I think what I need is a break from this script. It is making me crazy. Listen. I'm going to credit you for for the answer as you have stuck with me and offered me a lot of help. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

If you set a session variable, then do a header redirect, you need to add session_write_close() before the redirect or you will lose your sesson modification.

Comment: Thanks superfro. Do I add that before or after the header function?

Comment: Add it after and it will be fine.

Comment: I could not even imagine that any comment can be even worse than the answer itself, but you did it ;-) The last comment is even worse.

Comment: so what is your suggestion zerkms?

Comment: @Superfro, I tried adding it before and after the header function but it still isn't working. I can see that it sets the data in the session then forwards over to the index page where it tests to see if the session data is set. It fails and then forwards back over to the login page.

Comment: @zerkms, I thought it was a little strange too but hey, I'm really desperate here. :D

Comment: @dpmguise: i've added my answer

Comment: You have to have something wiping out your varaible then,  Try changing it to a javascript redirect instead of a header location.

Answer (score 0):

Something that I've ran in to quite a bit is accidentally redirecting from a page with 'www.' in the URL to a page without. I'm not exactly sure why it happens but for some reason the session between a site is different with and without the 'www.'.

Comment: According to his snippet, He's redirecting to / so it should be the same exact host name, just different path.

Comment: Hey Aaron, I read about that too and I'm on a local dev machine pointing to localhost. Thanks for the heads up though.