# Weird issue with a session

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I had this weird issue and I finally realized that it was due to a single session by which I determined whether the user's logged in or not. ($_SESSION['uID']) Everything was working alright until all of a sudden this very session was unavailable in ONLY ONE of my files! I mean it still worked on my localhost but not when I tried to reach it on my actual server.

If sessions are stored in some files, I suspect there might be an issue with the server and still if so, why the session is not available in ONE of my files only?

**Edit**: The problem is **not session_start()** as I already have it on my file(s). If I use another name for this session it works again.

**Edit 2**: This guy (Here: [session wiped out between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130295/session-wiped-out-between-pages)) seems to have the same issue but as you can see he could get no answer either. Anyone?

**Edit 3**: Here's a sample of both working and problematic files:

Session uID is available in this file:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!empty($_SESSION['username'])) { // USER Active - SESSION Active
    $userLoggedIn = "1"; // login flag
    $uID = $_SESSION['uID']; // here it returns a valid value
    dbconnect();

    // and the rest (this file works ok)

}
?>
```

And it is not available in the following file

```
<?php
// Jan 2012
session_start();

if (!empty($_SESSION['username'])) { // SESSION Active
    $userLoggedIn = "1"; // login flag

    $pID = ""; // initiating
    $uID = "";
    $NewStat = "1";

    $pID = $_POST['pID'];
    $uID = $_SESSION['uID']; // This is were it returns null!

    // on direct use die
    if (!$pID || !$uID || $pID == "" || $uID == "") die("ERROR 33");
        require_once ("./functions.php");
        dbconnect();

        // Getting info from db and stuff...

        echo $starFile;

    } else {
        die("ERROR sd23");  
}
?>
```

Comment: It would be **super** neat if we could get a look at your files.  One working, one not working.  That would be **super** helpful.  Mmmk?

Comment: How are you getting into the second file?  Is it after a `header('Location: ...');` redirect, or something else?

Comment: No, these are merely reached from a homepage using href (e.g. one is used for rating and stuff and the other is used to display some information)

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you don't call `session_start()` in that file.

Comment: I know but there is already a session_start() on its 3rd line.

Comment: the session_start() should be the first line of a page

Comment: That's not the problem Ampere, the first line(s) are merely some comments.

Comment: The session is configured the same way on each page? Seeing some of your code would help...